# How to add row data to first occurrence of string field

Tags: sql

I have found many examples of how to remove duplicate rows, but they all involve rows with a unique integer id.

Here is what I need to know. I want to merge all the duplicate stringIDs together and sum the values of the other columns.

I have this:

```
stringID | v1 | v2 | v3
    a    | 2  |  3 | 4
    b    | 5  |  4 | 1
    a    | 1  |  1 | 2
    b    | 2  |  1 | 1
```

I want this:

```
stringID | v1 | v2 | v3
    a    | 3  |  4 | 6
    b    | 7  |  5 | 2
```

Thank you for the help.

EDIT
I am using MySQL

Comment: Which RBDMS is this for?  MySql? Sql Server? Oracle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think just a simple `GROUP BY` and `SUM()` should give you the results you're looking for:

```
SELECT
  StringID,
  SUM(v1) AS v1,
  SUM(v2) AS v2,
  SUM(v3) AS v3
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY StringID
```

[See it in action with Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a8fd0/2).

Comment: Thank you, it work! Actually, I don't need to change the data, I'll just create a view :) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

(disclaimer: with SQL-Server >= 2005)

So you want to update first with the sum of all records, then you want to delete the dups:

Update:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT stringID, 
           v1_sum = SUM(v1) OVER (PARTITION BY stringID),
           v2_sum = SUM(v2) OVER (PARTITION BY stringID),
           v3_sum = SUM(v3) OVER (PARTITION BY stringID),
           RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY stringId Order By stringId)
    FROM dbo.TableName
)
UPDATE tn SET v1 = v1_sum, v2 = v2_sum, v3 = v3_sum
FROM CTE c 
INNER JOIN dbo.TableName tn ON c.stringId=tn.stringId
WHERE c.RN = 1;
```

Delete:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT 
        RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY stringId Order By stringId)
    FROM dbo.TableName
)
DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RN > 1;
```

[**DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/13b80/13/3)

Comment: Thank you. Querying the data was fine, but this is very nice to know.

Comment: @viau_a: You're welcome. However, i have seen your mysql-edit too late, so this approach works only with MS SQL-Server.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
select stringID, sum(v1), sum(v2), sum(v3)
from yourtable
group by stringID
```